Decomposition of a homology class $C \in H_2(X, \mathbb{Q})$ of a smooth projective complex algebraic variety

Let $ X $ be a smooth projective complex algebraic variety of
dimension $ n $.
Prove that for any homology class $ C \in H_2(X, \mathbb{Q})$, the
following two conditions are equivalent:

$$\int_C \alpha = 0 \text{ for all holomorphic 2-forms } \alpha .$$
$$\text{There exist algebraic curves }X_1, \ldots, X_n  \text{ on } X \text{ and rational numbers } m_1, \ldots, m_n \text{ such that }$$
$$C = m_1 [X_1] + \cdots + m_n [X_n],$$
where  $[X_k]$ are the homology classes of the curves $ X_k $ in $ H_2(X, \mathbb{Q})$.


I'm struggling with this problem. Additionally, is the Cone Theorem related to this? I read that the Chow group of $X$ has a similar decomposition.

One direction is easy, since on every Riemann surface the zero form is the only holomorphic 2-form.

@red_trumpet Could you elaborate your idea? In any case, since we have $[X_i]:=[X_i^{sm}]$, then $\int_{X_i}\omega=\int_{X_i^{sm}}\omega$ implies the required, right?

Yeah that's what I had in mind.

I am not sure about connections with the Cone Theorem. This is a classical application of the Hard-Lefschetz and the Lefschetz $(1,1)$ theorem in the context of the Hodge Conjecture. Although, $C$ is given as a homology class, I can use Poincare duality to think of it as an element of $H^{2n-2}(X;\mathbb Q)$. Under this identification $\displaystyle{\int_C \alpha}=\int_{X}C\wedge \alpha $

Since $X$ is smooth projective, it is Kahler and we have, by the Hard Lefschetz theorem the isomorphism, $$L^{n-2} : H^{2}(X;\mathbb Q)\xrightarrow{\cong} H^{2n-2}(X;\mathbb Q)$$where $L$ is a hyperplane class. In fact this fits into the commutative diagram involving rational Chow groups denoted by $A^k(X)$ . $\require{AMScd}$ $$\begin{CD}
 A^1(X) @>{\cap L^{n-2}}>> A^{n-1}(X)\\
@V{cyc}VV @V{cyc}VV\\
 H^{2}(X;\mathbb Q) \cap H^{1,1}(X) @>L^{n-2}>{\cong}>H^{2n-2}(X;\mathbb Q) \cap H^{n-1,n-1}(X)
\end{CD}
$$

Now by the Lefschetz $(1,1)$ theorem, the left vertical arrow in the above commutative square is surjective and hence so is the right vertical arrow.
We show that $C\in H^{n-1,n-1}(X)$.

Since $C$ is a rational cohomology class, it has the Hodge decomposition $C= C^{n,n-2}+ C^{n-1,n-1}+ C^{n-2,n}$ where $C^{n,n-2}=\overline{C^{n-2,n}}$ But the condition says that for all $\alpha $ holomorphic $2$-forms, we have $\displaystyle{\int_X C\wedge \alpha}=0\implies \int_X C^{n-2,n}\wedge \alpha=0$ for all $\alpha \in H^{2,0}(X)$. But by the non-degeneracy of the integration pairing, we see that $C^{n-2,n}=0$ and hence $C^{n,n-2}=0$.

So $C\in H^{2n-2}(X;\mathbb Q) \cap H^{n-1,n-1}(X)$. This completes the proof in one direction.
As for the other direction, if $C=\sum_im_i [X_i]$ where $X_i$'s are algebraic curves (note that $X_i$'s need not be smooth), we get $C\in H^{n-1,n-1}(X)$ by the cycle class map. So if $\alpha$ is a holomorphic $2$-form, $C\wedge \alpha\in H^{n+1,n-1}(X)=0$ since $\dim X=n$ which essentially means $\displaystyle{\int_C \alpha =0}$.
Alternatively, you can use @red_trumpet's idea. Even though $X_i$ is not smooth, $\displaystyle{\int_{X_i}\alpha =\int_{X_i^{sm}}\alpha =0}$ where $X_i^{sm}$, the smooth locus is a Riemann surface.

what does it mean the map from $A^1\to A^{n-1}$? is it the intersection product?

Moreover, why does that diagram commute? is it a paring?

yes, the top horizontal arrow is the  intersection product. the commutativity follows from the functorial property of the cycle class map. A reference for this would be Fulton’s Intersection Theory or Voisin’s Complex Algebraic Geometry 2

$cyc: A^\bullet (X) \rightarrow H^{2\bullet} (X; \mathbb Q)$ is a homomorphism of graded rings.
